# The type or namespace name 'Objects' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data'

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, linq-to-entities, entities

I am using entities, C# and SQL Server to create an n-tier app. I am creating some base classes common to all my DAL components. In this base class, i want to handle the connection state of the ObjectContext base class inherited by entities object.

Compiling throws the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'Objects'
>   does not exist in the namespace
>   'System.Data' (are you missing an
>   assembly reference?)

Also, the using statement System.Data.Objects doesn't resolve for the same reason.

I tried adding the assembly as reference, but couldn't find it in the .NET tab of assembly references.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 213, accepted):

You need to add a reference to the .NET assembly System.Data.Entity.dll.

Comment: It worked! Curious, if the System.Data.objects namespace is indeed present within the System.Data.Entity?

Comment: hmm... I don't even see that when i search for it in nuget

Answer (score 58):

If you are using Entity Framework 6, the name space has changed. You want to use

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery
```

Comment: I have Entity Framework 6.1.3 installed through nuget package manager. I don't have YET referenced Microsoft's assembly System.Data.Entity. Its giving me errors. So my question is that do I need to reference System.Data.Entity FIRST before adding that using statement?

Answer (score 33):

Upgraded from EF5 to EF6 nuget a while back and kept encountering this issue. I'd temp fix it by updating the generated code to reference `System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects`, but after generation it would be changed back again (as expected since its generated).

This solved the problem for good:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/upgradeef6

> If you have any models created with the EF Designer, you will need to update the code generation templates to generate EF6 compatible code.
>   ***Note:*** There are currently only EF 6.x DbContext Generator templates available for Visual Studio 2012 and 2013.
>
> 1. Delete existing code-generation templates. These files will typically be named **<edmx_file_name>.tt** and **<edmx_file_name>.Context.tt** and be nested under your edmx file in Solution Explorer. You can select the templates in Solution Explorer and press the <kbd>Del</kbd> key to delete them.
>      ***Note:*** In Web Site projects the templates will not be nested under your edmx file, but listed alongside it in Solution Explorer.
>      ***Note:*** In VB.NET projects you will need to enable 'Show All Files' to be able to see the nested template files.
> 2. Add the appropriate EF 6.x code generation template. Open your model in the EF Designer, right-click on the design surface and select **Add Code Generation Item...**
>
>    - If you are using the DbContext API (recommended) then **EF 6.x DbContext Generator** will be available under the **Data** tab.
>        ***Note:*** If you are using Visual Studio 2012, you will need to install the EF 6 Tools to have this template. See [Get Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712906#tooling) for details.
>    - If you are using the ObjectContext API then you will need to select the **Online** tab and search for **EF 6.x EntityObject Generator**.
> 3. If you applied any customizations to the code generation templates you will need to re-apply them to the updated templates.

Answer (score 4):

if you want to use "System.Data.Objects.EntityFunctions"

use "System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions" in EF 6.1+

Answer (score 3):

Same problem in VS 2013

I added in Web.config :

```
<add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
```

It worked like a charm.

I found it on page:
http://www.programmer.bz/Home/tabid/115/asp_net_sql/281/The-type-or-namespace-name-Objects-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-SystemData.aspx

Answer (score 3):

In my case for EF 6+, when using this:

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery
```

As part of this command:

```
var sql = ((System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery)query).ToTraceString();
```

I got this error:

```
Cannot cast 'query' (which has an actual type of 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<<>f__AnonymousType3<string,string,string,short,string>>') to 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery'
```

So I ended up having to use this:

```
var sql = ((System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<<>f__AnonymousType3<string,string,string,short,string>>)query).ToString();
```

Of course your anonymous type signature might be different.

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

For EF6, replace  "xxxx.Context.cs" with these using

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a reference to the .dll file, for System.Data.Linq,
the above was not sufficient.  You can find .dll in the various directories
for the following versions.

System.Data.Linq
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Data.Linq.dll
3.5.0.0

System.Data.Linq
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Data.Linq.dll
4.0.0.0

Comment: Correction this answers a question where  : The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data'

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a reference to the .NET assembly System.Data.Linq

Comment: Hi Null29, can you explain how your answer is better than the ones already provided?