# The type or namespace name 'Objects' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, monodevelop

I'm using MonoDevelop on Mac OS X Snow Leopard to develop an ASP.NET MVC Application. I have tested it on Visual Studio 2008 on Windows 7 and it worked fine, but when compiling it on MonoDevelop it throws the error: `The type or namespace name 'Objects' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data'` under this line: `public partial class MoviesDBEntities : global::System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext`

I'm not sure what the EXACT problem here is but I'm assuming I'm missing something from what the error is saying. How do I rectify this? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The type or namespace name 'Objects' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275043/the-type-or-namespace-name-objects-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-system-dat)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that there's [not yet an implementation of the Entity Framework](http://www.mono-project.com/Compatibility) for Mono. [Maybe some day](http://www.mono-project.com/EntityFramework). Currently there's no chance you compile this under Mono.

Answer (score 2):

Entity Framework 6 is now available on Mono.
http://www.mono-project.com/EntityFramework
You can reference EntityFramework.dll.