# System.Data.Entity.SqlServer namespace in EF5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nuget

I need to use SqlFunctions and I have a dependency to EF5.
In EF5 I can't find the System.Data.Entity.SqlServer namespace, (I searched for it in Syste.Data.Entity assembly).
If I migrate to EF6 I can find it, but for my project I can't migrate (I have transitive dependencies coming from other projects).

How can I use SqlFunctions in EF5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the `System.Data.Objects.SqlClient` namespace? (as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

Comment: I don't find the System.Data.Objects namespace in my references even if I have System.Data.Entity.dll as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275043/the-type-or-namespace-name-objects-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-system-dat. I find EF versions and Framework overlaps a bit messy...