# how to use sql function in linq

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I want to change this procedure to linq for entity framework:

```
SELECT COUNT([dbo].[Events].[Request]) as requestCount, 
MONTH([dbo].[Events].[Request]) as months
FROM [dbo].[Events]
GROUP BY MONTH([dbo].[Events].[Request])
```

I used many solution but none of them works!
Thanks in advance!

Edit: Solutions that I use them:
 solution 1:
[The type or namespace name 'Objects' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275043/the-type-or-namespace-name-objects-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-system-dat?noredirect=1&lq=1)

but I never find SqlFunctions!!

solution 2:

```
var events = db.Events.GroupBy(x => Convert.ToDateTime(x.Request).Month)
                      .Select(g => new { max = g.Max(), Count = g.Count() })
                      .ToList();
```

give me this error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime
>   ToDateTime(System.DateTime)' method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression.

Comment: You don't need a sql function for `MONTH`, you can use the `Month` property of `DateTime`. By the way, you ignore the year in this query.

Comment: _I used many solution but none of them works!_ - add one to the question so we can help you fix it

Comment: OK, I edited my question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var events = db.Events.GroupBy(x => x.Request.Month)
                      .Select(g => new { Month = g.Key, RequestCount = g.Count() })
                      .ToList();
```

If `Request` isn't a `DateTime` like your example might infer then you can:

```
var events = db.Events.Select(item => new 
                            { 
                                Month = DateTime.Parse(item.Request).Month,             
                                Event = item
                            })
                      .GroupBy(x => x.Month)
                      .Select(g => new { Month = g.Key, RequestCount = g.Count() })
                      .ToList();
```

And just for the fun of it you can use a different overload of `GroupBy` (where the `select` lambda is another parameter:

```
var events = Events
    .Select(item => new
        {
            Month = DateTime.Parse(item.Request).Month,
            Event = item
        })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Month, 
        (key, collection) => new 
        { 
            Month = key, 
            RequestCount = collection.Count() 
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: @amirstack - Added another way of doing :)